# Mergesort recurrence formulas - reconciling reality with textbooks

Tags: algorithm, big-o, mergesort, recurrence

I think this is more programming than math, so I posted here.

All the java algorithms in my question come from [here](http://kosbie.net/cmu/summer-08/15-100/handouts/IterativeMergeSort.java).

We have an iterative and recursive merge sort.  Both using the same merge function.

The professor teaching [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKp7dok7-Bg) lecture says that the critical operation for merge sort is the comparison.

So I came up with this formula for `merge()` based on compares:

```
>3n + 2
```

3: worst case compares through each loop.
n: amount of times loop will iterate.
2: the "test" compares.

The `recursiveMergesort()` has the base case compare plus the recursive calls for a total of:

```
>T(n/2) + 1 + 3n + 2 = T(n/2) + 3n + 3
```

The `iterativeMergesort()` simply has one loop that runs `*n/2*` times with a nested loop that runs *n* times.  That leads me to this formula (but I think it's wrong):

```
>(n/2) * n + 3n + 2 = (n^2)/2 + 3n + 2
```

The books say that the recurrence formula for the recursive mergesort is

> 2T(n/2) + theta(n)

Which solves with the master method to

> theta(NlogN)

**Question 1:**
How are the formulas I created simplified to

> T(n/2) + theta(n)

**Question 2:**
Can I use any of these formulas (the ones I created, the textbook formula, or the time complexity `*theta(nlogn)*`) to predict number of compares when running ***this particular algorithm*** on an array size *n*

**Question 3:**
For the bonus:  Is my formula for the iterative method correct?

Merge:

```
private static void merge(int[] a, int[] aux, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
   // DK: add two tests to first verify "mid" and "hi" are in range
   if (mid >= a.length) return;
   if (hi > a.length) hi = a.length;
   int i = lo, j = mid;
   for (int k = lo; k < hi; k++) {
      if      (i == mid)     aux[k] = a[j++];
      else if (j == hi)      aux[k] = a[i++];
      else if (a[j] < a[i])  aux[k] = a[j++];
      else                   aux[k] = a[i++];
   }
   // copy back
   for (int k = lo; k < hi; k++)
      a[k] = aux[k];
}
```

Recursive Merge sort:

```
public static void recursiveMergesort(int[] a, int[] aux, int lo, int hi) {
   // base case
   if (hi - lo <= 1) return;
   // sort each half, recursively
   int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
   recursiveMergesort(a, aux, lo, mid);
   recursiveMergesort(a, aux, mid, hi);
   // merge back together
   merge(a, aux, lo, mid, hi);
}

public static void recursiveMergesort(int[] a) {
    int n = a.length;
    int[] aux = new int[n];
    recursiveMergesort(a, aux, 0, n);
}
```

Iterative merge sort:

```
public static void iterativeMergesort(int[] a) {
  int[] aux = new int[a.length];
  for (int blockSize=1; blockSize<a.length; blockSize*=2)
     for (int start=0; start<a.length; start+=2*blockSize)
        merge(a, aux, start, start+blockSize, start+2*blockSize);
   }
```

Wow, you made it all the way down here.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the book's definition of theta(N)? Is it any different than big O notation `O(n)`?

Comment: I think when he says comparisons are the critical part he doesn't mean comparison of indices, which are always integers. Think of an array of objects whose `compareTo()` method has to access all their fields.  The critical comparison is actual element comparison.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll: yes.  theta(n) includes the lower and upper bound.  O(n) is just the upper bound.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: so `else if (a[j] < a[i])` is the only critical operation then?  What about the swaps (`aux[k] = a[j++]`)?  Are they critical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1:**

Where are you getting your facts? To obtain `theta(nlogn)` complexity you need

```
T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n), where a > 1, b > 1 and f(n) = cn + d. c != 0
```

Note: There are additional constraints, dictated by the [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

You cannot derive from reccurence relation based on `T(n) > T(n/2) + 3n + 3`. You probably forgot that the cost of an array of size n is the cost of the merge plus ***twice*** the cost of each part. So rather

```
  T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 3n + 3
```

**Question 2:**

You cannot use theta, Big O or Big Omega to predict number of compares when running this particular algorithm on an array size n. Because they are asymptotic expressions. You need to solve the relation above, assuming it is correct.

For instance `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 3n + 3` [has the solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+2T%28n%2F2%29+%2B+3n+%2B+3)

```
T(n) = 3n log2(n) + 1/2(c+6)n - 3, c constant
```

Still this is the number of comparisons of the algorithm. All optimizations and constraints of a real program are not considered.

**Question 3:**
Nope

Comment: I did forget the 2 in figuring out how to ask the question.  So how do I get from `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 3n + 3` to `2T(n/2) + theta(n) to use the master method?  Is it simply that `3n + 2` is in theta(n)?  What's a good way to figure out the correct iterative formula.  Thanks

Comment: I think I see my error in the iterative.  Both loops increase by 2 * the "blocksize".  Therefore it's the same, 2T(n/2).

Comment: `3n + 2` is in theta(n). Easy to prove when you look up Knuth definition

Comment: @MayNotBe Hi. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this